# Declare a signal of the same type as another signal (VHDL)

Tags: syntax, signals, vhdl

Is it possible to declare a signal of the same type as another signal in VHDL?

For example, assume that we have the following signal declaration:

```
signal address_q : integer range 0 to 31;
```

I need to declare a variable `address_d` that will be of the same type as the `address_q` variable (`integer range 0 to 31`). Is it possible to do this by using built-in signal attributes, or in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `subtype` attribute is probably what you are looking for:

```
entity foo is
end entity foo;

architecture bar of foo is
  signal address_q : integer range 0 to 31;
begin
  process
    variable v: address_q'subtype;
  begin
    report to_string(v'subtype'left);
    report to_string(v'subtype'right);
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture bar;
```

Simulation with GHDL:

```
foo.vhd:10:5:@0ms:(report note): 0
foo.vhd:11:5:@0ms:(report note): 31
```

Note: this attribute has been introduced in VHDL 2008. Do not try to use it with older versions of the VHDL standard.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but unfortunately, it doesn't work in pre-2008 versions.

Comment: This also nicely solves a problem I was having with GHDL where it would not let me say something like `address_q'high` - It does seem to accept `address_q'subtype'high` though...

Answer (score 1):

**1st way:**

You may declare more signals at once separating them by commas.

```
signal address_q, address_d : integer range 0 to 31;
```

**2nd way:**

You may declare your type first and then use it for all signal declarations.

```
type my_type is integer range 0 to 31;

signal address_q : my_type;
signal address_d : my_type;
```

Comment: I know how to use both of these, but I was hoping that there might be some trick using signal attributes to get the signal type, something like `type my_type is signal'type`

Comment: @MarkoGulin OK. I have rushed. :)

Comment: You haven't, I didn't specify in the question what exactly do I want. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: Keep the answer, it is one of the possible solutions to the original question. I'll accept the answer if there is no other way of doing this.